# Accessing Spell Check through PPTX

Tags: python-pptx

Do we have an option in python-pptx to read the spell check mode used in the presentation? I am working on a project in which I have to check the spell check mode is set to "UK English". Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The spellchecker language is part of a font. You can get it via `font.language_id`. For possible values, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.msolanguageid?view=office-pia).